# Where are the opacity map presets for CC Particle World in CS5 and CS6?

Tags: after-effects

In versions of After Effects prior to CS5, there are opacity map presets such as Fade In, Fade Out, Constant, etc.

I can see Opacity Map under Particle in the CS6 CC Particle World, but how do I get the presets?

Answer (score 2):

In the newer versions of CC Particle World the opacity map presets have been removed.

The only way to set opacity now is by drawing a curve on the graph.  See screenshot below:

[image: Opacity map CC Particle World screenshot]

Comment: is there any way to reset the Opacity Map? Its really hard to just draw on.

Comment: So the opacity map in cs5 also changed? So there isn't any other way to use the old presets except by drawing a curve on the graph?